# iPhone UIViewController Lag

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, xib, lag

I have a 'detail' page where I am displaying info for a club. The page is a UIViewController and consists of buttons and labels to acheive this look (like small grouped tables). When I load this page on a device, it lags a bit, more than any other view in my app.

I assume its because I have quite a few objects on the view controller. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to reduce this lag? Or how to achieve the look the 3 smaller tables like this(grouped) in a different way?

Thanks.

SCREENSHOT:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try making custom tablecells and use UITableView instead?

Comment: Would I have to make 3 separate tables? Is that possible all in one class?

Comment: You could just use one single tableview. Just design a cell that looks like the one you have made and use it. Pretty simple. If you didn't get it ask and I can try to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the view a UITableView using `UITableViewStyleGrouped` style, and then programmatically create the cells for each row. Overriding

`- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

gets you your titles like "Meeting Information" and "Contact", and overriding

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

gets you correct sizing on each table cell. If the text in "General Information" is not going to be a constant size, you can use the

`-sizeWithFont::(UIFont *)font`

method of NSString in your heightForRowAtIndexPath implementation.

Comment: You may need to use `-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` so you can change the font size and use a background.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not likely your interface design. UI drawing is pretty snappy usually.  The things that slow it down are accessing data.  If you have a large data set you are searching you might look at ways to speed that up.

Comment: I had a different UI with the same data and there was no lag.